# Library not updating

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm working on a project in Android Studio which uses some 3rd party libraries.
One of these is the WeekView (https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View). As I'm european, I decided to change the date/time format to a more european one (24h-format, dd.MM instead of MM/dd) in the source of the lib.
But these changes seem to not affect the project at all. Everything I changed did not have any effect. I tried rebuilding, restarting Android Studio, rebuilding with the gradle references removed, nothing helped.

What do I need to do to let the changes take effect?

I edited the following in file "/src/main/java/com/alamkanak/weekview/WeekView.java" (the original parts are commented out):

```
public DateTimeInterpreter getDateTimeInterpreter() {
    if (mDateTimeInterpreter == null) {
        mDateTimeInterpreter = new DateTimeInterpreter() {
            @Override
            public String interpretDate(Calendar date) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf;
                sdf = mDayNameLength == LENGTH_SHORT ? new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE") : new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
                try{
                    String dayName = sdf.format(date.getTime()).toUpperCase();
                    return String.format("%s %d.%02d", dayName, date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); //return String.format("%s %d/%02d", dayName, date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String interpretTime(int hour) {
                //String amPm;
                //if (hour >= 0 && hour < 12) amPm = "AM";
                //else amPm = "PM";
                //if (hour == 0) hour = 12;
                //if (hour > 12) hour -= 12;
                //return String.format("%02d %s", hour, amPm);
                return hour + ":00";
            }
        };
    }
    return mDateTimeInterpreter;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a code snippet where you are trying to change date settings?

Comment: @IvanV I added the changed code

Comment: I don't know anything about this lib but, either extend some appropriate class you can use variable shadowing, or do it the way ypu are doing but make aure you are modifying the source code and not a documentation file or something (Ctrl+B), also check that you are modifying every reference to that timezone variable

Comment: Did you try to use `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what the problem was: The library was compiling directly from GitHub. I had to change the Gradle configuration to compile the code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");` and then format the date `simpleDateFormat.format(new Date())`

Make sure that "HH" in the formatting are uppercase, cause it corresponds to European 0-23 hour format, whereas lowercase "hh" corresponds to 1-12 format.

More about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).